# derivative of $y= (\frac{x}{x-1})^x - \frac{x}{x-1}$

Tags: derivatives

I would like to work out the sign of the first order derivative of $y= (\frac{x}{x-1})^x - \frac{x}{x-1}$ with respect to x.

I get this:
$dy/dx = (\frac{x}{x-1})^x \left(-\frac{1}{x-1} + ln\frac{x}{x-1} + (\frac{1}{x-1})^2 (\frac{x-1}{x})^x \right)$

when I plot this function, for $x>1$, I see that as $x$ increases, $y$ decreases.

I understand that $ln\frac{x}{x-1} \leq \frac{1}{x-1}$, but we have this extra term $(\frac{1}{x-1})^2 (\frac{x-1}{x})^x$, how do I prove that $dy/dx < 0$?

Answer (score 1):

*This is not a full answer.*

Writing the derivative in a different way, we have
$$y'=\frac{1+(x-1) \left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)^x \left((x-1) \log
   \left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)-1\right)}{(x-1)^2}$$ So, the problem is "just" the sign of the numerator.

Expanding as a Taylor series around $x=1$, we have
$$y'=-(x-1)+\frac{1}{2} (x-1)^2 \log ^2(x-1)+O\left((x-1)^3\right)$$ WHich is negative at least for small values of $x$.

Similarly, for large values of $x$,
$$y'=\left(1-\frac{e}{2}\right)+\frac{e}{12 x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ which is also negative.

Now, what happens between these two points ?